# Does Azure charges for using VPN in SQL Database Managed Instance?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am planning to use Azure SQL Database Managed Instance, but not sure if using VPN will be charged or not. Microsoft Doc's on this are quite confusing and doesn't clearly mention about VPN pricing.

Comment: Check the prices https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/ . I don't think the vpn's price depends on connected seriveces.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay for any bandwidth consumption related to data going out of Microsoft Azure Data Centers. You can get more information about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/).

If you are looking for pricing of VPN Gateway and Express Route Gateway you can visit [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/) Microsoft page.